# how to stop a looping javascript in firefox?

Tags: firefox, javascript

I have a constellation of html/css/js-files and somehow I coded a loop in there, since the same js-file loads over and over again.

I'm using firefox, F12 will no longer bring the console forward, I have to click on the menue manually to get it, and when it opens, the loop is in full action, spitting out my console.log's over and over.

There is no "X" in the navigation-area of firefox, just the reload-circled-arrow, so I can't just stop the script (since, obviously all files are already downloaded).

I can't really read the log either due to the speed at which it runs.

Now, I haven't yet tried to wait for a time-out, but is there any other way to stop a looping javascript inside firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one possible method to narrow-down the search for the loop.

I suggest using the
[debugger command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger):

> The debugger statement invokes any available debugging functionality, such as setting a breakpoint. If no debugging functionality is available, this statement has no effect.

Therefore, you need to open the Dev Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) before loading your
website.

The method of debug is to sprinkle your code with `debugger;` statements,
so as to pause the JavaScript and break into the debugger.
Move these statements in the code so as to narrow-down the area where is located
the loop.
(Don't forget to take them all out once finished.)

This method takes time and patience, but it will help in locating the loop.